# LMS の Moodle に教師ロールでログインした際、コースに登録されている他の参加者を非表示にさせる方法はありますか？

Tags: moodle

Moodleのロール設定についての質問になります。

学生ロールは元々ほかの参加者がみれないように設定されているため問題ないのですが、教師ロールにおきまして、Moodleの「ロールの定義」の設定で参加者表示をすべてオフにして教師ロールでログインした場合でも、ほかのコース参加者がみれてしまいますので、もしご存じであれば教師ロールでの参加者非表示設定のしかたをご教示いただけますと幸いです。

※Moodle側で設定した内容：

1. 管理者でログイン⇒「サイト管理」へ
2. 「ユーザー」⇒「パーミッション」⇒「ロールを定義する」に進む
3. 該当するロール（今回は教師）のところに表示されております、右側の歯車マークをクリック
4. 「参加者を表示する」：許可のチェックを外す（二つ該当項目があるので、両方とも許可のチェックを外す。）

Answer (score 1):

Moodle の利用者ではないので推測での回答となります。

ドキュメントを読む限り、教師ロールはコースに対しての管理者に近い権限のようなので、そもそも「他の利用者を見えなくする」という設定自体があまり良い方法(=考え方)ではないように感じます。

(標準の) 教師ロールではなく、別のカスタムロールを作成してみてはどうでしょうか？

[カスタムロールの作成 | MoodleDocs](https://docs.moodle.org/3x/ja/%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90)

Comment: 今後、カスタムロールを検討していこうと思います！cubick様、ご回答ありがとうございます。